# Mark last set of items dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have a dataset of sales orders that are divided into product lots. Want to apply a flag to **all** the lots of the last order within a given year in Pandas / Python. Any advice?

Currently have:

```
masterDF['FLAG'] = masterDF.groupby(by=['id','year'],as_index=False)['ordernumber'].nth(-1)
masterDF['LAST_ORDER_OF_QUARTER'] = np.where(masterDF['FLAG'].isnull(),0,1)
```

But that only puts a `1` on the last row of the dataframe, not on *all* rows within that given order if that `ordernumber` appears on more than one row.

To illustrate:

```
ordernumber   |   lot      |    Last Order of Quarter
------------------------------------------------------
orderA        |   lot1     |     0
orderB        |   lot1     |     1
orderB        |   lot2     |     1
```

Any advice?

Comment: You are using columns that aren't listed here. Can you please provide a proper [mcve]?

Comment: @user791411 Hi, please add an example of your data. And is your illustrate - desired output?

Answer (score 0):

example dataset:

```
event_id,type,timestamp
asd12e,click,12322232
asj123,click,212312312
asd321,touch,12312323
asdas3,click,33332233
sdsaa3,touch,33211333
```

We want to apply a label to the last orders from column 'id_type'. In the first place, we assing the last type order to an index. In order to do that:

```
indexes = df.drop_duplicates(subset='type',keep='last').index
```

Then we need to generate a new boolean column 'label'. This column will be False in case that it does not verify the condition and True in the opposite case. Note: int type will be used in order to improve the computation:

```
df['label'] = 0
# Assign True conditions to the indexes:
df.loc[indexes,'label'] = 1
```